Excel Charts - Stacked Chart: Reduce Spacing and Combine Categories
I have the following data which produces the following chart:
I am trying to change the Axis so the month is shown once and the years data have no spacing between them, for example trying to only have Jan and the years for Jan shown as 4 attached bars. Rearranging the Month and Year in the data has not worked. I am using Excel 365.

After the Answer by MGonet below, i have this graph by taking out the month for each line and adding spaces but need to take out the spaces in between the years.


Do you mean something like that?


Ha! didnt think taking out the months on every line and adding spaces will help, i just dont know how to take out the spaces in between

Gap Width = 0% see e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQs0p3VxmZQ
